# remove COMMENT '' from table created in mysql workbench 6.3

Tags: mysql

```
   CREATE TABLE `new_schema`.`new_table` (
      `idnew_table` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
      `new_tablecol` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`idnew_table`)  COMMENT '')
    ENGINE = InnoDB
    PACK_KEYS = DEFAULT
    ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;
```

When I create a new table in MySQL workbench 6.3 COMMENT '' is auto-generated at the end. How can i remove this auto-generated COMMENT ''.

Comment: I'd like to ask you to think about filling it in instead. That way others looking at your table have some idea what's going on.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: Hello Matei Mihai, 

i am aware about that comment but i get ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMENT '')' at line 4

Comment: Index comments were supported in MySQL 5.7. Are there (in workbench) any options to select desired MySQL version for scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Mysql Workbench 6.3.4 has a bug and can not create proper SQL command for MySQL lower than 5.5.

Quick fix is manual edit SQL code to remove `COMMENT ''` in the window just before pressing <kbd>Execute</kbd> or <kbd>Apply</kbd> button.

[image: Remove marked text]

You can also downgrade to one of previous versions which do not have this bug.

PS. There was a bug like this in older versions thus it looks like some regression bug:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57849